# Looping Function for inputing multiple SKU's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query information from a list of about 150 SKU's accross a few different tables. So far I've attempted to do a Select, Where, and From statement but don't want to keep doing OR statements 150 times. Is there a way to loop the code and get the information the following way:

```
SKU   ProductName  Introduction Date   Suggested Retail Price   Units Sold  
1234    Cream             6/12/2019               $5.47              50
```

The databases are the following

SKU - is Item No_ from table dbo.v_Nav_PurchasePriceCurrent

Product Name - is Description in table [NAV-WH].[dbo].[Threshold Enterprises$Item]

Introduction Date - is Starting Date from table dbo.v_NAV_PurchasePriceCurrent

Suggested Retail Price - is Suggested Retail Price from table dbo.v_NAV_PurchasePriceCurrent

Units Sold and Amount Sold - I obtain by using the following code:

```
DECLARE @SDate date
SET @SDate = '12/31/2018'
DECLARE @EDate date
SET @EDate = '5/30/2019'


SELECT        SUM(Amount) AS EXPR1
FROM            dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Sales Invoice Line]
WHERE        ([Shipment Date] BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate) AND (No_ = 
N'SN1580')

SELECT        SUM(Quantity) AS EXPR1
FROM            dbo.[Threshold Enterprises$Sales Invoice Line]
WHERE        ([Shipment Date] BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate) AND (No_ = 
N'SN1580')
```

Code Below is the closes I've gotten to getting the information but trying to get it all in one along with the code I posted above for Amount Sold

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT        TOP (1000) [Item No_], [Suggested Retail Price], [Starting 
Date], [Ending Date], [Price Source]
FROM            dbo.v_NAV_PurchasePriceCurrent
WHERE        ([Item No_] = N'SN1793') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1794') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1795') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1201') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1202') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN2636') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN2637') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN2185') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN2186') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1213') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1214') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1732') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1945') OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1946')OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1947')OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1766')OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1767')OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1768')OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN2138')OR
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN2139')or
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1201')or
                     ([Item No_] = N'SN1201')
```

My expected results are posted below with an extra column including amount sold

```
SKU   ProductName  Introduction Date   Suggested Retail Price   Units Sold  
1234    Cream             6/12/2019               $5.47              50
4565    Pill              1/1/2019                $4.55              45
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to loop? Where does the list of [Item No_] come from? This seems like you need to learn how to use a join, not a loop.

Comment: I am trying to loop a list of SKU's for example I've used code where I've Declared a variable and inserted a list of SKU's to return the information back in a table.

Comment: [Item No_]  comes from                                                                                       SKU - is Item No_ from table dbo.v_Nav_PurchasePriceCurrent

Comment: Ah. If you want to use a variable with a delimited list of SKUs, your best bet would be to search here for string splitting functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest solution would use an IN statement, like this:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT        TOP (1000) [Item No_], [Suggested Retail Price], [Starting Date], [Ending Date], [Price Source]
FROM          dbo.v_NAV_PurchasePriceCurrent
WHERE         [Item No_] IN (N'SN1793', N'SN1794', N'SN1795', N'SN1201', N'SN1202', N'SN2636', N'SN2637', 
                             N'SN2185', N'SN2186', N'SN1213', N'SN1214', N'SN1732', N'SN1945', N'SN1946', 
                             N'SN1947', N'SN1766', N'SN1767', N'SN1768', N'SN2138', N'SN2139', N'SN1201', 
                             N'SN1201')
```